# How can I determinate if a function grows ir decreace much faster than other function?

Tags: real-analysis

For example, how can I know if the function: $\frac{x}{2}$ grows faster than $\log(x)$?

I mean how can I know if the function $\frac{x}{2}$ takes higher values than $\log(x)$ (for example) in the whole range and domain of the function.

Comment: Take the limit of the ratio as x tends to infinity

Comment: The questions you're asking are not precisely the same. If you want to tell on which subsets of the domains of $\frac{x}{2}$ and $\log(x)$ does the following occur: $\frac{x}{2}>\log(x)$, this is an inequality which must be solved for $x.$ If, however, you wish to talk about the relative order of magnitude of these functions, or their asymptotics, then one question about those is: does $\frac{x}{2}$ grow "faster" than $\log(x)$ as $x\to\infty$? To answer that, you may look up the concept of "Big O and little o notation", and there you can find the relevant tools to answer this question.